# How much power do Home Solar Panels provide?

Tags: simcity-2013

How much power does the solar panels on the homes provide or what % of its power is supplied by those solar panels? Is there a varying level of solar panels on each home or is it either YAY or NAY?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://twitter.com/MaxisGuillaume/status/314508463445266433

*yeah it makes power for them -- almost 100% for D1, 30% for D2 and 10% for D3*

I'm assuming that D is short for density...

Answer (score 4):

**The solar panels provide power during the day, and rely on the city power grid during the night.**

See Maxis Guillaume´s Twitter for more info:
https://twitter.com/MaxisGuillaume/status/292408871199313922

There doesn't seem to be any specific information regarding how much power the solar panels provide for each home during the day cycle.

For information regarding SimCity 5 (2013) power sources, see this link.
http://simcity.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Power_Plants
(buttom of the page)

There is great information regarding the different options.

Comment: In a newer tweet of his, he indicated that the % power savings scaled by education level (something like up to 50% for 5/5 cities).

Comment: Nice info! Could you provide a link to the Twitter update you ref. too? :)

Comment: I googled the tweet -- looks like the % savings doesn't scale by education but rather by decreases by density. I put the tweet as an answer

Comment: Good job user43524

Answer (score 2):

I believe those solar panels remove the power requirements of the house it's installed on during the day only.